# TFlite GPUDelegateV2 suffers from long initial time

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am inferencing model using tflite with GPUDelegateV2 from tf2.X, but the initial time seems to be so long, check the table as below:

The model I'm using comes from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet), and I test these data using benchmark_model following [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark#on-android)

TF version: 2.0.0
benchark_model parameters:

> - use_gpu=true
> - num_threads=1
> - allow_fp16=true
> - others by default

```
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|v3-small_224_1.0_float|inference time(ms)| initial time(ms) |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       on CPU         |      46.245      |       2.988      |
|   on GPUDelegateV2   |      13.015      |      4480.14     |

|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
| mobilenet_v2_0.75_224|inference time(ms)| initial time(ms) |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       on CPU         |      123.116     |       2.849      |
|   on GPUDelegateV2   |      27.084      |      6358.39     |
```

I tried with different models / devices but got results just alike
(faster initial on newer cores but still much longer than how they work on CPU).

Is there anyone have some idea about this?

Comment: Could you share the setup code you use and the devices you've tested this on?

Comment: @NickShebanov Hello, I tried on SnapDragons cores such as 855. Benchmark_model is built as what tensorflow indicate, thanks.